# Failed to send an ICMP packet through socket on Android API 22 (Lollipop)

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin, ping

I wrote a small app that pings a remote server by sending ICMP packets using sockets (Android's Os package). I tested it on the API 28 emulator and it worked, but it does not work on API 22 (Android 5.1 Lollipop). I tested it on the VD as well as on my smartphone (same old API) with the same negative result

```
android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

I debugged the app on different API versions and the only difference I noticed that `ByteBuffer.wrap()` produces `ByteArrayBuffer` instance on API 22 and `HeapArrayBuffer` instance on newer versions. The payload itself seems to be the same.

Here is the code sample (simplified). Also, there is a test application available: https://github.com/alexeysirenko/android-sockets-icmp-ping-test
You could try to launch it on the different emulators (API 22 and >22) and see the difference

```
private val timeoutMs = 5000
private val delayMs = 500L
private val ECHO_PORT =  80
private val POLLIN = (if (OsConstants.POLLIN == 0) 1 else OsConstants.POLLIN).toShort()

fun ping(host: String): Unit {
    val inetAddress: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host)
    if (inetAddress is Inet6Address) throw Exception("IPv6 implementation omitted for simplicity")
    val proto = OsConstants.IPPROTO_ICMP
    val inet = OsConstants.AF_INET
    val type = PacketBuilder.TYPE_ICMP_V4
    val socketFileDescriptor = Os.socket(inet, OsConstants.SOCK_DGRAM, proto)
    if (!socketFileDescriptor.valid()) throw Exception("Socket descriptor is invalid")    
    var sequenceNumber: Short = 0
    for (i in 0..2) {
        sequenceNumber++
        val echoPacketBuilder =
            PacketBuilder(type, "foobarbazquok".toByteArray())
                .withSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber)
        val buffer = echoPacketBuilder.build()

        /**
         * This is the command that throws an exception
         */
        val bytesSent = Os.sendto(socketFileDescriptor, buffer,0, buffer.size, 0, inetAddress, ECHO_PORT)

        // Response processing code omitted
    }
}

class PacketBuilder(val type: Byte, val payload: ByteArray, val sequenceNumber: Short = 0, val identifier: Short = 0xDBB) {
    private val MAX_PAYLOAD = 65507
    private val CODE: Byte = 0

    init {
        if (payload.size > MAX_PAYLOAD) throw Exception("Payload limited to $MAX_PAYLOAD")
    }

    fun build(): ByteArray {
        val buffer = ByteArray(8 + payload.size)
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)

        byteBuffer.put(type)
        byteBuffer.put(CODE)
        val checkPos = byteBuffer.position()
        byteBuffer.position(checkPos + 2)
        byteBuffer.putShort(identifier)
        byteBuffer.putShort(sequenceNumber)
        byteBuffer.put(payload)
        byteBuffer.putShort(checkPos, checksum(buffer))
        byteBuffer.flip()
        return buffer
    }

    fun withSequenceNumber(sequenceNumber: Short): PacketBuilder {
        return PacketBuilder(type, payload, sequenceNumber, identifier)
    }

    /**
     * RFC 1071 checksum
     */
    private fun checksum(data: ByteArray): Short {
        var sum = 0
        // High bytes (even indices)
        for (i in 0 until data.size step 2) {
            sum += data[i].and(0xFF.toByte()).toInt() shl 8
            sum = (sum and 0xFFFF) + (sum shr 16)
        }

        // Low bytes (odd indices)
        for (i in 1 until data.size step 2) {
            sum += data[i] and 0xFF.toByte()
            sum = (sum and 0xFFFF) + (sum shr 16)
        }

        sum = (sum and 0xFFFF) + (sum shr 16)
        return (sum xor 0xFFFF).toShort()
    }

    companion object {
        val TYPE_ICMP_V4: Byte = 8
    }
}
```

If my code is incorrect then I'd expect the same error on all platforms, but as I said it does work on all APIs newer than 22 and I do not know exactly what causes this issue

Comment: 21/22 and 23 versions have different Linux kernel versions 3.16.1 and 3.18.10 respectively. `Os` is low level API, so problem can occur because of different  Linux kernel versions and requirements. Probably you should research on sendTo(2) Linux documentation. But it is just a guess.